How to group rows in dataframe based on timestamps ranges and mean group size maximization?
I have a data frame:
prod_id                    timestamp1                 timestamp2
1                          2023-12-02                 2023-12-01    
2                          2023-12-05                 2023-12-01    
3                          2023-12-06                 2023-12-01    
4                          2023-12-07                 2023-12-01    
5                          2023-12-08                 2023-12-01
6                          2023-12-08                 2023-12-02
7                          2023-10-10                 2023-09-02
8                          2023-12-11                 2023-12-22 
9                          2023-12-12                 2023-12-24

I want to group prod_id (create new parameter group_id) by timestamps ranges. the distribution of dates at timestamp1 must not exceed 3 days (so the difference between max and min within group_id must be no higher than 3 days). Similarly, the distribution of dates at timestamp 2 must not exceed 3 days (so the difference between max and min within group_id must be no higher than 3 days). I need to maximize the average number of prod_id per group_id. so here the desired result must be:
prod_id   timestamp1      timestamp2          group_id
1          2023-12-02    2023-12-01               1
2          2023-12-05    2023-12-01               2
3          2023-12-06    2023-12-01               2
4          2023-12-07    2023-12-01               2
5          2023-12-08    2023-12-01               2
6          2023-12-08    2023-12-02               2
7          2023-10-10    2023-09-02               3
8          2023-12-11    2023-12-22               4
9          2023-12-12    2023-12-24               4

as you see here prod_id is in group_id 2 because it will create larger group_id, than if it was in group_id 1, even though it could be in group_id 1 by conditions. so this grouping maximizes the mean number of prod_id per group_id.
How to do it? I wrote this, but it doesn't have algorithmic maximization of the mean number of prod_id per group_id:
df['timestamp1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp1'])
df['timestamp2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2'])
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['timestamp1', 'timestamp2'])

group_id = 1
df_sorted['group_id'] = 0

while not df_sorted.empty:
    group_start = df_sorted.iloc[0]
    valid_rows_t1 = df_sorted[(df_sorted['timestamp1'] <= group_start['timestamp1'] + pd.Timedelta(days=30))]
    valid_rows_t2 = valid_rows_t1[(valid_rows_t1['timestamp2'] >= valid_rows_t1['timestamp2'].min()) &
                                  (valid_rows_t1['timestamp2'] <= valid_rows_t1['timestamp2'].min() + pd.Timedelta(days=30))]
    df_sorted.loc[valid_rows_t2.index, 'group_id'] = group_id
    df_sorted = df_sorted.drop(valid_rows_t2.index)
    group_id += 1


Here is a code to create tha dataframe:
# Create the dataframe
data = {
    'prod_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'timestamp1': ['2023-12-02', '2023-12-05', '2023-12-06', '2023-12-07', '2023-12-08', '2023-12-08', '2023-10-10', '2023-12-11', '2023-12-12'],
    'timestamp2': ['2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-01', '2023-12-02', '2023-09-02', '2023-12-22', '2023-12-24']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


I'm pretty sure that this problem is NP-hard. Greedy is easy. There are ways to generate other decent solutions. But perfect is unlikely to be feasible.

Putting prod_id 2 into group_id 2 does not improve the mean number of prod_id per group_id. In both cases you would have 4 groups and 9 product ids, so the average would be 2.25, the same for both of them.

In your "desired result" the numbers of products per group are 1 for group 1, 5 for group 2, 1 for group 3 and 2 for group 4, so the average number per group equals (1+5+1+2)/4 = 9/4. Is that the quantity you wish to maximize?

@btilly could you suggest some decent solution please?

@CarySwoveland yeah you are right both solution have equal means. but idea of what should be maximized is clear. i’m more interested in how to maximize it. what approach to use

@btilly interval scheduling task seems close

If g groups are used, the average number of products per group will be 9/g, 9 being the number of products. In your example 1+5+1+2 = 9, but regardless of how products are allocated to groups the numerator must equal the number of products, here 9. So your problem appears to be equivalent to minimizing the number of groups. Correct? I'll give it some thought.

@CarySwoveland yeah correct its minimization of the number of groups. but clossest solution i found is "interval scheduling maximization problem"

I believe a greedy solution will minimize the number of groups, which is equivalent to minimizing the average number of products per group, since that average equals P/g, P being the total number of products (regardless of how they are allocated to groups) and g is the number of groups.
Suppose we are given any solution where two successive groups are given by gi and gi+1. These groups are comprised of products as follows.
gi = [pf,...,pj]
and
gi+1 = [pj+1,...,pk]
Suppose now product pj+1 can be moved to group gi and satisfy the date requirements for the that group. Moreover, moving that product out of group gi+1 will not violate the date requirements for that group.
If group gi+1 contains only one product, pj+1, moving that product to the previous group will reduce the number of groups by one, improving the solution; otherwise, the number of groups will remain the same so the average number of products per group will not change.
This means that a solution is never made worse by shifting the first product of a group to the previous group, provided that is permitted by the date requirements. By doing that successively until no other product can be so moved we obtain the solution what would be obtained by employing a greedy algorithm: add as many products to group 1 as possible until the date requirements prevent the next product, pj from being added, at which point pj becomes the first product of group 2, and so on.
For the example given in the question a greedy algorithm would result in the following.
prod_id    timestamp1    timestamp2      group_id
1          2023-12-02    2023-12-01          1
2          2023-12-05    2023-12-01          1
3          2023-12-06    2023-12-01          2
4          2023-12-07    2023-12-01          2
5          2023-12-08    2023-12-01          2
6          2023-12-08    2023-12-02          2
7          2023-10-10    2023-09-02          3
8          2023-12-11    2023-12-22          4
9          2023-12-12    2023-12-24          4

This differs from the "desired solution" given in the question in only one respect, product #2 is allocated to the first group rather than to the second, but both solutions have the same average number of products per group, (2+4+1+2)/4 #=> 9/4 versus (1+5+1+2)/4 #=> 9/4, so both are optimal.

fries, I don't know Python but it appears you have employed a greedy algorithm in which case your solution would be correct. We might ask @btilly or...

...@Nick to confirm that.
